# I am using Postgresql shell (this file and directory is not found)

Tags: python, django, rest, psql, mysql-shell

I get this:

> You are now connected to database "test" as user "postgres".
> test=# \i C:/Users/ANUJ MISHRA/Downloads/human.sql
> C:/Users/ANUJ: No such file or directory

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be using a directory that has at least one SPACE
character in it, and that interferes with command line parsing.

Quote the filespec, use `\`  to insert a literal SPACE character,
or put the *.sql files of interest in another directory
whose pathname lacks SPACEs.

Comment: I tried this but it's doesn't work 

Comment: I find it hard to believe that using a pathname without SPACEs didn't improve matters. Ok, here's another tack: initially `cd` to the `Downloads/` directory before invoking the `psql` program. Then a very short pathname of just `human.sql` should suffice.